# Query with results approached like google search in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause

how to get result query like google search in active record rails?

```
example 1 :

User.all

result :
[{name: "john now", age: "14"}, {name: "desy awesome", age: "19"}]

example 2 :
User.where("name LIKE ?", "%jo%")

result :
[{name: "john now", age: "14"}]
```

my question is, when i search name "johnnow" i want get result like bellow. Example :

```
User.where("name LIKE ?", "%johnnow%")

    result :
    [{name: "john now", age: "14"}]
```

how do that?

Comment: How big is the table `users` you have?

Comment: You'd need a dictionary of some sort to split strings, like if `john` occurs in a string then split the string there and search on the split terms.

Comment: You can use full-text search libraries for the sake. for example `thinking-sphinx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sort of thing is really for a search engine, rather than SQL. There are many other ways you might want things to match in a fuzzy way e.g. case-sensitivity, misspellings etc. Trying to cover it all with complex SQL will send you slowly insane.

I use [Searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) for this, but there are many other alternatives. You will need a search indexer e.g. Elasticsearch or Solr, then a gem of some sort to tie it into your AcitveRecord classes.

Using Searchkick for the `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick
end
```

Then in the terminal:

```
User.reindex
```

Then search:

```
users = User.search 'johnnow'
```

Comment: i get error "users = Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200"

Comment: Do you have elastic search set up correctly? It sounds like you do not have this running. Use homebrew to install it on a mac and make sure you run it before doing anything else.

Comment: you right, i' forget running elastichsearch xD
thank you @Matt Gibson